# Can't upload XML file to FTP using node-ftp or jsftp

Tags: xml, node.js, ftp

I am trying to upload few files to ftp using node.js [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp) modules, I have few files to upload among them some are audio and image file and one is XML file , I can upload all image and audio file successfully but when I try to upload XML file than it gives me error as below:

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

I have set NODE_DEBUG = net to debug socket calls. I also try to implement [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) but it also gives log for ECONNRESET and not more information, I also try to use [jsftp](https://github.com/sergi/jsftp) but still I am getting the same error. I don't know why this error is comming. below is the code I used to upload XML file to server

```
c.put('temp.xml','drop/metadata.xml',true, function(err) 
{
        console.log(err);
        if (err)
        {
                console.log('Inside error');
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
       }
       console.log('upload successfully');
});
```

Comment: HI, i have the same issue, maybe you found some decision?

Comment: I use https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2 because your ftp may have SFTP protocol.  it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to using [keepAlive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsftp#ftpkeepalivewait) after Ftp init step:

```
var Ftp = new JSFtp({
        host: config.get("ftpDownloader:host"),
        port: config.get("ftpDownloader:port"), // defaults to 21
        user: config.get("ftpDownloader:user"), // defaults to "anonymous"
        pass: config.get("ftpDownloader:pass"), // defaults to "@anonymous"
        debugMode: false
    });
Ftp.keepAlive();

//.. do Ftp.get.. or Ftp.ls.. methods
```